# Custom websocket handshake

Tags: java, authentication, kotlin, websocket, handshake

I have a `ServerEndpoint` and a `ClientEndpoint` exchanging JSON messages via the respective encoders/decoders.

Now I want to add the ability for a client to choose a unique user name.

Let's say I have a `fun isNameAvailable(name: String): Boolean` (on the server, of course).

Haven't tried it, but I do think I could use a `WebFilter`s to guard access to WebSocket endpoints. (e.g. let's say I connect to `ws://localhost:8888/ws/foo` and I add a web filter that intercepts all accesses to `/ws/*`) in which I'd query the user repeatedly for a user name and reject it until `isNameAvailable` returns `true`.

But in my understanding, that fails as soon as I add a non-browser client.

How can you write a "custom handshake"?

I.e. I want to repeatedly query the client for a `String` from within the `ServerEndpoint`'s `@OnOpen` until one fits and only then continue with the rest of the setup, after which the client and the server can start exchanging the JSON messages. That is, something like this:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/foo")
class FooServerEndpoint{
    @OnOpen
    fun open(session:Session){
        var userName:String
        do{
            userName = requestUserName(session)
        }while(!acceptUserName(userName,session)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do that?

**UPDATE: Technology Used**

`JavaEE 8`/`Kotlin 1.3.21`, deployed to a `Glassfish 5` server and connected to by a `Glassfish Tyrus 1.15`-based client

Comment: It would be beneficial for the readers to know which java ee/kotlin version you are using. It would be great if you update your question and/or tags.

Comment: @FlorianDe that would be `JavaEE 8`, `Kotlin 1.3.21`, running on a `Glassfish 5` server and connected to by a `Glassfish Tyrus 1.15`-based client. I'll add the info to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at creating a custom ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator and overload the modifyHandshake() method and apply this instance to your server endpoint as the configurator property of the @ServerEndpoint annotation?
Similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21766822/11133168

You could also find more details on this topic in the book "[The Java EE 7 Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/JEETT.pdf)" in Chapter 18.10